# How to write query similar to this with codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is the mysql query i want to write with codeigniter

```
SELECT r.reciept_no,r.loan_no,r.amount_paid,c.mem_name  
FROM receipts r, customer c 
WHERE r.loan_no = c.loan_no AND reciept_no = '$receipt_id'
```

any help would be great

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head

```
$this->db->select('receipts.reciept_no');
$this->db->select('receipts.loan_no');
$this->db->select('receipts.amount_paid');
$this->db->select('receipts.reciept_no');
$this->db->select('customer.mem_name');
$this->db->where('reciept_no', $receipt_id);
$this->db->join('customer', 'receipts.loan_no = customer.loan_no');
$this->db->get('receipts');
```

The JOIN beeing key here

Answer (score 0):

just a small modification :

```
$sql = 'r.reciept_no,r.loan_no,r.amount_paid,r.reciept_no,c.mem_name';

$this->db->select($sql)
->where('reciept_no', $receipt_id)
->join('customer as c', 'r.loan_no = c.loan_no')
->get('receipts as r');
```